# How make command usable in aiogram?

Tags: python, aiogram

I try to make command usable after entering password, please help. This command doesnt work after password.

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import StatesGroup, State

import config

TOKEN = "mytoken"
bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)


class FSMInputName(StatesGroup):
    name = State()


@dp.message_handler(commands=["start"])
async def process_start_command(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Чтобы войти, введите команду /password")


@dp.message_handler(commands=["password"])
async def cmd_pass(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("Введите пароль")
    await FSMInputName.name.set()


@dp.message_handler(state=FSMInputName.name)
async def state_pass(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['password'] = message.text
        if message.text == "hksdf":
            await message.answer("Введите команду /number, чтобы ввести номер клиента")

            @dp.message_handler(commands=["number"])
            async def cmd_num(message1: types.Message):
                await message1.answer("Введите номер")
                await FSMInputName.name.set()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

I try to make command "/number" usable after entering password

Comment: `This command doesnt work after password.` please give more details, do you see an error? if so which one? Does just nothing happen?

Answer (score 0):

Зачем тебе такие глубокие сложности?
Если хочешь обойтись только FSM - сделай так (не пишу очевидного типа класс фсм и так далее)

```
password = State()
authorized = State()

@dp.message_handler(state=FSMInputName.password)
async def password_handler(message: types.Message):
    if message.text == "hksdf":
        await message.answer("Введите команду /number, чтобы ввести номер клиента")

@dp.message_handler(commands=["number"], state=FSMInputname.authorized)
async def cmd_num(message1: types.Message):
    await message1.answer("Введите номер")
```

Дальше делаем с номером что захотим. Хоть сохраняем, хоть валидируем а потом сохраняем. Если это чисто для себя - ок, если для группы людей - лучше посмотри как взаимодействовать с БД (хватит и sqlite3)